# c# windows forms autocompleate with separators

Tags: c#, autocomplete, windows-forms-designer

I try to type 1 or more E-Mail adresses separated by an ";" both shoud be completed automatic with the AutoComplete Event after typing the first letters. The first autocomplete working fine, but the second don´t show me an suggestion. I filled the AutoCompleteCustomSource with a collection of some test E-Mails.

```
string[] collection = filled with some E-Mails        
Collection.AddRange(collection);
this.receiverInput.AutoCompleteCustomSource = Collection;
```

with this 2 lines i set the Event for the textbox:

```
this.receiverInput.AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
this.receiverInput.AutoCompleteSource = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
```

Can someone help me to fix this problem? In the end it shoud 
look similar to the outlook receiversline.

[example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsATF.png)

Comment: Im guessing because to auto complete you'd have needed that combination of recipients in the list.. so recipients of "me","you","him","her".. if youve got those in the list you may auto complete, but the rest wont because you dont have "you,him" as a recipient combo

Comment: I tried it and this is working, but if in my Collection of E-Mails are the Mail adresses "test@mail.com" and "test@mail.com;test2@mail2.com" it´s show me the second string as suggestion what isn´t looks nice... I hoped for a solution witch show only the next possible adress and not the full string of all mail-adresses .... i hope you know what i mean

Comment: i know what you mean but ive never tried to do any more than the required combinations

Comment: Nevertheless, thanks I'll use it as a 2nd option if I can´t find a nicer solution.